# Every finite Borel measure on a separable metric space is tight.

Tags: measure-theory, metric-spaces, borel-measures, polish-spaces

I'm trying to prove this property of Polish space. Could you verify if my attempt is fine?

> Let $(X, d)$ be a complete separable metric space. Then every finite Borel measure on $X$ is tight.

I post my proof separately as below answer. This allows me to subsequently remove this question from unanswered list.

Comment: It's probably best to post a proof attempt as part of the question, rather than as an answer.

Comment: @JoseAvilez I observe that people tend to comment rather than write an answer. I guess it's partly because their answer is quite short. It makes my question "unanswered" even though I already got one. That's why I post my proof separately. This allows me to subsequently remove this question from unanswered list. If other people post an answer, of course I will accept theirs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $D := (a_i)_{i=1}^\infty$ be a countable dense subset of $X$. For each $m \ge 1$, $$
\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty B \left(a_{i}, 1/m\right) = X.
$$
Fix $\varepsilon > 0$. For each $m \ge 1$, there is a natural number $k_m$ such that
$$
\mu \left ( \bigg (\bigcup_{i=1}^{k_m} B \left(a_{i}, 1/m\right) \bigg )^c \right ) \le2^{-m} \varepsilon.
$$

Let
$$
K := \bigcap_{m=1}^\infty \bigcup_{i=1}^{k_m} \overline B \left(a_{i}, 1/m\right).
$$

Clearly, $K$ is closed and thus complete. Moreover, $K$ is totally bounded, so it's compact. We have

$$
\mu(K^c) \le \varepsilon \sum_{m=1}^\infty 2^{-m} = \varepsilon.
$$

This completes the proof.

Comment: @JoseAvilez $K \subseteq \bigcup_{i=1}^{k_m} \overline B \left(a_{i}, 1/m\right)$ for all $m \ge 1$.